# Некорректная работа tkinter Pydroid

Tags: python, tkinter, pydroid

Написал код в Pydroid:

```
from tkinter import*
win=Tk()
win.mainloop()
```

Запустил, белый фон и больше ничего. Хотелось бы увидеть окно с конкретными границами, с заголовком. Когда дописал в коде win.title("Заголовок"), также ничего не изменилось. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться...

Comment: А что должно быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Этот код создает просто пустое окно. Для pydroid это видимо эквивалентно белому фону. Какой результат вы хотели получить?

Comment: Вопрос отредактировал.

Comment: Если вы ожидали увидеть окно как на Windows/MacOS, то такого не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Зайти в Pydroid 3
2. Нажать на три полоски
3. Settings
4. System
5. Пролистать в самый низ
6. Отключить "Tkinter: maximize first window".

Все готово!

Comment: Всем большое спасибо! Ответы помогли. Проблему решил!

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо за +15 репутации! <3

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать в настройках pydroid отображение заголовка, так как по умолчанию окно открывается во весь экран. левое меню-система-листай в самый низ- maximize first window выключить.